# SharePoint SSA slow search after not searching for a while

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search, sharepoint-search

I am experiencing issues with my SharePoint Search Service Application.

If I start a search query after a while (about 30 minutes), the result page loads for almost half a minute. However normally it only takes 1 or 2 seconds. Has anyone experienced this before?

Im using SharePoint Foundation 2013 with SQL Server 2012 R2 SP1

Thanks for your help,

Colin

Comment: What version of SharePoint  you are using?

Comment: SharePoint Foundation 2013

Comment: Are you using separate web application for search center by any chance, maybe it is a warm up issue? The usual culprit in this case is the revocation check of certificates. Enable CAPI2 (from Windows) logs on the FE and Search server and see do you have any issues (like revocation check failed)

Comment: Alright I checked my LOG files and found the following:
A certificate validation operation took 14581,1762 milliseconds and has exceeded the execution time threshold.  If this continues to occur, it may represent a configuration issue.

I do not have any Internet connection on my SharePoint Server so that might be a problem.

Comment: That might be it. Now you need to check which cert it is and why the operation is timing out on your machine. Does it have internet access, if not there are ways of dealing with that depending on  your case. If you have issue with the SP root importing it the cert to root cert store should help as well.

Comment: I will try this, Thanks